# what/where is the default yum conf and server

Tags: package-management, yum, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have 2 new redhat hosts (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9). 
Lets call them A and B.  They both run on 2 different networks.

I try to run the 'yum -update' command on both hosts. 
Works on A, and updates packages.

Fails on B. Looks like the command times out in its attempt to reach the server that holds the pkgs/info.

```
[root@den-mon1 log]# yum -v update
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
Config time: 0.084
```

I have not modified the /etc/yum.conf file on A or B.
In /etc/yum.repos.d , i see one file - rhel-debuginfo.repo
Its contents -

```
[rhel-debuginfo]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Debug
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/$releasever/en/os/$basearch/Debuginfo/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
```

Question - Where is the default conf for Yum, and which default server does it try to reach out to to obtain pkg info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several yum config files

`/etc/yum.conf` - main config file

`/etc/yum.repos.d/<repo_name>.repo` - additional repository, ie EPEL, RPM forge, etc that compatible with the distribution version.

`/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date` - Used by rhnsd agent and can be configured to connect to RHN hosted or RHN Satellite servers.

As for the connection failing on Host B, its probably related to the way you set up your network. Check if there is a blocked port going out to the internet. Please check your output from `/var/log/up2date.log` to see whats happening.

You probably don't need rhel-debuginfo repo, that's for developers who want more info when debugging an app.

Comment: found this line in up2date file - serverURL=h t tp s: // xmlrpc.rhn.redhat.com/XMLRPC

 ... i believe that line dictates the location for retrieval of package information.

Comment: so port 443 is probably blocked to that server.

Comment: the problem was a misconfigured resolv.conf.
host didnt have conn to a dns server, which means it couldnt connect to anything outside our little n/w.
fixed the dns, and now yum works.